# Hybridauth: How can I allow user to choose Facebook account after they log out?

Tags: facebook, laravel, hybridauth

I'm using HybridAuth with Laravel.  How can I allow the user to choose a (different) Facebook account after logging out of my UI?

Currently, when the user logs out then in, it auto logs them into my site because they have received a token previously.  They are not given an option to log into a Facebook account.  Therefore, the user can only use one Facebook account with my site, ever.  I tried deleting session data as well as $hybridAuth->logoutAllProviders(); and it still happens.

I could set the Force Web OAuth Reauthentication setting in Facebook for my app, but I don't want the user to log into Facebook every time they visit my site.  I would like them to be able to switch Facebook accounts they want to use with my site.

I get expected behavior when logging as a Google user.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Users are not supposed to have multiple Facebook accounts anyway, so this would be a valid scenario only for different people using the same device in any case. And if you want to switch users, then you have to log the current user out of FB first. Check the hybridauth documentation for how to do that.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if someone logs into a site that uses social authorization and logs out they will have a false sense of security because they have to log out of any IDP's they used to log in otherwise (on a shared device) if someone visits the same site they only need to choose the same IDP and they would have site access to the previous user's account.  But if you auto log out the user from their IDP, for security reasons, they will most likely have a negative user experience on your site because they will have to re-log their IDP if they log out of your site.

Comment: Yes, users have to be more careful when they log in to anything on a shared device … what else is new? :)

Comment: Perplexing.  If oauth can't revoke the user's access token for a particular site without logging them out of the IDP why have a logout button at all?  Should we instead display "You must log out of IDP".  Or have a link to log them out of their IDP, for convenience?  Am I missing something?  Thanks for your insight!

Comment: The OAuth system is just more geared towards convenience, assuming you’re using your own device, I guess. If I log in to anything on a device that isn’t mine, or that others are using as well, then I have to log out after I’m done – I’m fine with that. Plus, private browsing exists.